# PHP change variable to corresponding type

Tags: php, mysql, variables, variable-types

I'm making a website in PHP with different config files depending on the company thats using it at that moment.

Every company has +/- 15 config files with all the same variables but ofcourse, different values. Now every company has to be able to easily change the settings so we are saving the settings in a MySQL database. The database has 3 columns 'company_id', 'setting' and 'value'.

When i'm reading the config items from the database, the variable type is always a 'string'. So ofcourse, the if statements "if($setting->value === false)" fails...

Is there an easy way to change the type of the variable corresponding the returned value from the database?

Comment: Have you tried if(!$setting->value)

Comment: Are you looking settype http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php ?

Comment: @Sari Rahal: Yes i have tried that, but even that if statement fails...

Comment: @Vladimir: I do know that function but i still have to change to type manually for all the different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store arbitrary types in a single database column, you'll have to serialise them into a string representation, from which you can unserialise the value again. PHP offers [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) for this purpose, but you can also use a language-neutral format like [JSON](http://php.net/json_encode), XML or YAML.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for! Got it working now. Thanks! :) **edit** Using serialize and unserialize...